# How do I forward websocket communication through an intermediary server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, websocket

I'm trying to connect a websocket server (linux machine) and client (web browser) through an intermediary server (hosted on an AWS EC2 instance). The EC2 instance provides a public IP that the websocket server and client can reference.

My client connects to `ws://<SERVER>:<PORT>`, where `SERVER` is the address of my EC2 instance and `PORT` is an arbitrary port  I've opened for port forwarding (e.g. `9111`).

On the websocket server, I'm running the following command:

```
  /usr/bin/ssh -f -N -i $KEY -l ubuntu \
                 -R $PORT:127.0.0.1:9090 \
                 -L 9090:$SERVER:$PORT \
                  $SERVER
```

Where `$KEY` is a private key for EC2 and `9090` is the port my websocket server uses. I've configured my EC2 instance's ssh daemon to enable gateway ports, and port forwarding is working just fine.

The issue comes when I try to start my websocket server -- I get an `Address already in use` error, because apparently I can't start a websocket server on a port that I'm forwarding. Isn't this a fairly standard thing to do? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your '-L 9090' option to SSH is opening a listener on port 9090, which conflicts with your websocket server. The -R option should suffice, and the forwardd connection will be bi-directional, you don't need to set up a 'reverse route' with -L.

You may need to enable the GatewayPorts option on your EC2 SSH daemon to be allowed to set up ports using -R that accept connections from any IP, in addition to any firewall changes.